# "*" is appearing top in CSS specificity, why?

Tags: css, css-specificity

I'm having trouble understanding why my CSS isn't being styled according to the way I understand the specificity rules.  According to my reading across the web (including [this calculator](http://specificity.keegan.st/)), the `*` (matches everything) has no specificity, while an element (e.g. `h1`,`h2`, etc) has is fourth most important, while a class is third most important.  But that's not what I'm seeing in the Chrome debugger.
[image]

From the looks of it, the `*` has come out on top, followed by the `h5`, then two more `*` matches and then a match for the class `.orange`.  Shouldn't the `*` be after everything else?  And shouldn't the `.orange` win out over the `h5`?  What is going on?

Comment: could you also provide some html?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your example, the `*` is the only selector that actually *matches* the element in question.

The other styles are only *inherited* by other element's definitions. These other elements are in a parent context with your element.

According to your screenshot, it must be `some-element` inside a structure like this:

```
<div class="row orange">
    <div class="col-xs-10">
        <h5 class="detail1">
            <some-element></some-element>
```

With regard to your element, inherited styles do not have any specificity at all. Specificity is a concept that applies to *CSS selectors*, not *CSS properties*.

> [Specificity of inherited CSS properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28420163/specificity-of-inherited-css-properties)

Comment: Oh, didn't notice `Inherited from ...` +1

Comment: Oh, ok!  In that case, how does inheritance work with specificity?  Even in that case, `div.row.orange` is still the most specific rule here and it's not winning.

Comment: With regard to your element, inherited styles do not have any specificity at all. Specificity is a concept that applies to *CSS selectors*, not *CSS properties*. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28420163/specificity-of-inherited-css-properties